# Firebase Database update user profile picture URL for all post

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, filter, firebase-realtime-database

Hi here my database structure for posts feed.
[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3vHw.png)

[image]

When I change the user profile picture I want to update all posts with the new image (under posts/***postID***/user/***userID***/image

If I have a ton of posts how to make it in the best way (atomaticaly)

I've try to do a query and then to update all the keys, but the query is not working on userID node.

Comment: In general, please post your actual firebase structure as TEXT please, no images or links. Text is searchable and if we need to use it in an answer, we can copy and paste it. You can get the text version from the Firebase console->Three dots on right->Export JSON. This is a good question.

Comment: I change the structure and didn't kept the old one. But I keep your advice in mind, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way.

Instead of duplicating all of the user details on every post, why not store the user details (including profile pic) in a structure like

```
/users/userID/name
/users/userID/profileURL
```

and then just store the posterID in the post

You will need to make two database calls to get the data, but if you update the profile picture once, it will be retrieved correctly for all posts

Comment: But at all posts call I will need to get the user related, so it's not efficient.
The full interest of firebase noSql style is the denormalization

Comment: what's the naming convention of your profile pictures?  If you're storing the picture for 'xyz' at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/xyz.jpg' then you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: it's like this but with a token from firebase for security

Comment: @ThierryZanzouri You're correct in that denormalization is normal. However, it very dependent on use case. In THIS use case we need to examine what it will take to update every single post a user makes with their new picture url vs denormalizing in a fashion shown in the answer. Yes, it's two firebase calls but MUCH easier to maintain and in the long run way more efficient - and comparing a single call to get a url for each post vs thousands of updates make this a very very good answer.

Comment: @Jay Generally the user change is picture very rarely so it's worth to do the full update, rather to do a sub query at every posts feed request.

I solve the problem by putting the userID as a key and value that I filter in a snapshot and then I do an atomic update

posts->postID->description,postImageURL,UserCreator->UserID,userName,imageURL